# Why do we need to subtract 1 from the size of the buffer to get the size of the column?

Tags: c

I'm making a program that takes a file of an unknown size as an input and dynamic allocate it as much as the size of the array. Why do we need to subtract 1 from the size of the buffer to get the size of the column?

This is part of the code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 500

void CountRowCol(FILE* fp);
void allocateMemory();

int main()
{
      FILE* fp = NULL;
      fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
      if (fp != NULL)
     {
        CountRowCol(fp);
        allocateMemory();
     }
      else
        printf("There is No file\n");

      fclose(fp);

      return 0;
 }

void CountRowCol(FILE* fp)
{
      int row = 0; int col = 0;
      char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
      if (fgets(buffer, 1000, fp))
     {
        col = strlen(buffer) - 1;
        row = 1;
     }
      while (fgets(buffer, 1000, fp))
     {
        row++;
     }
      fclose(fp);
      fp = NULL;
}
```

Comment: "I'm making a program" ... "Why do we need to subtract 1". I dunno man, that's your code since you're doing it. So why do you need to substract 1 ? And I don't know how your allocateMemory function is supposed to work, but I will be surprised if that's the case.

Comment: When there is `"abcde"` in the buffer and you want to have the index for the `e`, it is `strlen(buffer)-1`. The length is `5`, but indexes start with `0`, so valid indexes are from `0` to `4`.

Comment: `col` variable is not used in `CountRowCol()` function

Comment: _Why do we need to subtract 1_ - Maybe to not include the trailing "\n"  (the newline character is read by `fgets`)

Comment: With `MAXSIZE` set to 500, you allow `fgets(..., 1000, ...)` to access `buffer` out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we need to subtract 1 from the size of the buffer to get the size of the column?

As code does not use `col`, `col = strlen(buffer) - 1;` has no direct usefulness. [@shjeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921258/why-do-we-need-to-subtract-1-from-the-size-of-the-buffer-to-get-the-size-of-the/71921843#comment127088481_71921258)

---

Let us assume code is trying to find the length of the first line and  not count a final `'\n'` [@David Ranieri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921258/why-do-we-need-to-subtract-1-from-the-size-of-the-buffer-to-get-the-size-of-the/71921843#comment127088500_71921258)
.

`strlen(buffer) - 1`, code risks 2 mistakes:

1. A `'\n'` may not exist in `buffer[]`, so finding its offset is moot.  E.g. the line of input may exceed buffer space, so no `'\n'` saved.
2. Although rare to first *read* a *null character*, it is possible, then `strlen(buffer)` is an *unsigned* 0 and `strlen(buffer) - 1` is a very large value: `SIZE_MAX`.  Assigning that to an `int` leads to *implementation defined behavior*, possible returning `INT_MAX`.

A better way to lop off a potential `'\n'`:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
col = strlen(buffer);
```

---

**Wrong size**

User code is lying to `fgets()` as `buffer` is less than 1000 bytes. [@the busybee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921258/why-do-we-need-to-subtract-1-from-the-size-of-the-buffer-to-get-the-size-of-the/71921843#comment127088503_71921258)

```
#define MAX_SIZE 500
...
// if (fgets(buffer, 1000, fp))
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(buffer, 1000, fp
```

This reads a line (assuming it fits in 999 bytes, one byte is used for string terminator, '`\0`').

This line includes the newline character, `'\n'`.

Subtracting 1 excludes that.

---

You might additionally want to remove the line feed from the string:

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') {
    // reduce line length by 1 and overwrite newline with 0
    buffer[--len] = '\0';
} else {
    // handle line which does not end in newline
}
```

Missing newline might be because file ended and did not have newline at the end, or because line was longer than the buffer. Here you can probably just... print error message and exit, if you aren't required to handle such input.

Comment: OP is reading a file, not an input from an user. Then the file could not end with en '\n' but always will end with a 'EOF'. That is the meaning and purpose of this character.

Comment: @Dedey EOF is not a character in the file. Or of it is, it will get removed because file is opened in text mode.

Comment: @Dedey and indeed last line may not end with a newline, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

In the C standard library, the character reading functions such as getchar return a value equal to the symbolic value (macro) EOF to indicate that an end-of-file condition has occurred. The actual value of EOF is implementation-dependent and must be negative (but is commonly −1, such as in glibc). Block-reading functions return the number of bytes read, and if this is fewer than asked for, then the end of file was reached or an error occurred (checking of errno or dedicated function, such as ferror is often required to determine which).

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: EOF is a character, but OP should not count it. OP should only use it to know when to stop. That's why OP needs to substract 1.

Comment: FGETC(3)  
NAME
       fgetc, fgets, getc, getchar, ungetc - input of characters and strings

DESCRIPTION
       fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

Comment: @Dedey C `EOF` is not a character, it is a sentinel value _outside_ `char` range. And it can't be stored in a file, because it's value does not fit in one byte, basically by definition of what C `EOF` is.

Comment: If you like to explain your answer, please [edit] it directly. Don't put additions in the comments. -- However, since your answer is based on a wrong assumption, you might want to delete it.